# replacing all row values with shorter names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data set with tons of rows. I have one column in that data set with long row values. I want to rename these row values with shorter names in pandas automatically. What should I do?

My data is something like this:

[image]

and I want an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Dear @SeaBean please see this. Many thanks

Comment: You can use similar function as previous.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) function which encodes the different patterns of objects as an enumerated type (with different serial numbers).  You can use it as follows:

```
df['Col1'] = 'C' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Col1'])[0] + 1, dtype='string')
```

or if your Pandas version does not support `string` dtype, use:

```
df['Col1'] = 'C' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Col1'])[0] + 1).astype(str)
```

#### Demo

**Data Input**

```
data = {'Col1': ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df) 


             Col1
0  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1  YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
2  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
3  YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
4  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
5  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

  Col1
0   C1
1   C2
2   C1
3   C2
4   C1
5   C3
```

Comment: It is also possible to set the dtype instead of making another copy with `astype`. `df['Col1'] = 'C' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Col1'])[0] + 1, dtype='string')`

Comment: I got an error with this code " the data type string is not understood" then I changed the code in this way : df['Col1'] = 'C' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Col1'])[0] + 1).astype(str) and it works perfectly. Thanks @SeaBean for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['col1'] = 'C' + (df.groupby('Col1').ngroup() + 1).astype(str)
```